# Tibble object (in R) not recognizing numeric variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

Tibble seems to be messing up the variable type whenever I call it a certain way. Here's a working example:

```
a = rep(LETTERS[1:10], times=5)
b = 1:10
d = data.frame(a,b)
d = d%>%group_by(a)%>%summarize(total=sum(b))
mean(d[,"total"])
```

Strangely, it does work when I do

```
mean(d$total)
```

or when I do

```
mean(d[["total"]])
```

Unfortunately, I have to call the variable using `mean(d[,"total"])`; I can't use `d$total` because I'm passing the variable name within a function, and I can't use `d[['total']]` because that will not work for data frames.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: You can do `mean(d[,"total", drop = TRUE])`

Comment: Thank you both. I wasn't aware dataframes could handle d[['total']]. Thanks!